# .Net Core Controller Edit ActionResult errors

Tags: asp.net-core

On the HttpGet '.Select(user => new AspNetUser()' line for the HttpGet  i get 'a local or parameter named 'user' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter'

On the HttpPost, I get an error on the Listdata listdata line, The type or namespace name 'Listdata' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'.

```
    [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Edit(string id)
      {
        //Get user and return the Edit View
        AspNetUser user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id)
        .Select(user => new AspNetUser()
        {
          Id = user.Id,
          UserName = user.UserName,
          NormalizedUserName = user.NormalizedUserName,
          Email = user.Email,
          NormalizedEmail = user.NormalizedEmail,
          EmailConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmed,
          PasswordHash = user.PasswordHash,
          SecurityStamp = user.SecurityStamp,
          ConcurrencyStamp = user.ConcurrencyStamp,
          PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
          PhoneNumberConfirmed = user.PhoneNumberConfirmed,
          TwoFactorEnabled = user.TwoFactorEnabled,
          LockoutEnd = user.LockoutEnd,
          LockoutEnabled = user.LockoutEnabled,
          AccessFailedCount = user.AccessFailedCount


          // Add the remainder properties
        }).FirstOrDefault();
          return View(user);
       }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult 

   Edit([Bind("Id,Username,NormalizedUserName,Email,NormalizedEmail,
   EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,")] Listdata  listdata)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(listdata).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(listdata);
        }
```

My expectations are when I click on the Edit link in the Edit view page it will go to the user that I want to update their info and save that change on the Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared "user" twice here -

```
    AspNetUser user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id)
```

and here

```
    .Select(user => new AspNetUser()
```

> On the HttpPost, I get an error on the Listdata listdata line, The type or namespace name 'Listdata' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'.

As the error states, you are missing a using statement for that class. You either need to create Listdata or add a reference to the project it resides in.

Answer (score 0):

You have that error because you are define 2 user variable in same scope at  `AspNetUser user` and `.Select(user`

So change your code to this

```
 AspNetUser userInfo = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id) // here
    .Select(user => new AspNetUser()
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        UserName = user.UserName,
        NormalizedUserName = user.NormalizedUserName,
        Email = user.Email,
        NormalizedEmail = user.NormalizedEmail,
        EmailConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmed,
        PasswordHash = user.PasswordHash,
        SecurityStamp = user.SecurityStamp,
        ConcurrencyStamp = user.ConcurrencyStamp,
        PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
        PhoneNumberConfirmed = user.PhoneNumberConfirmed,
        TwoFactorEnabled = user.TwoFactorEnabled,
        LockoutEnd = user.LockoutEnd,
        LockoutEnabled = user.LockoutEnabled,
        AccessFailedCount = user.AccessFailedCount


        // Add the remainder properties
    }).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(userInfo);
```